# wordpress plus ajax using admin-ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have problem with using ajax in wordpress theme. I read all google first 5 pages and forum...i stucked.

So, i just in functions.php add these lines

```
function my_action_callback(){
    echo"aha";
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

and in my theme file - main.js add on click event, which send ajax call.

```
$('.load_more').click(function(){
  $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'http://www.mysite.eu/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
    data: { action: 'my_action'},
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
        alert('done');  
    },  
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
        alert('error:'+errorThrown);  
    }  
  }); 
});
```

and i always get - 'error:' with empty textStatus. WHY?? please, help me :(

Comment: Either remove `_callback` from your function or add it to `wp_ajax_` actions and the `action:` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your textStatus is not defined, just change the data parameter like this:

```
data: { 
  action: 'my_action', 
  textStatus: $('.other_div').val 
},
```

And now you will get no errors.